# How to get width and height by URL of string in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to get a width and a height value from an URL string. My URL is this:

```
let url = "uploads/story/5503113.jpg?854|1467";
```

In this URL, 854 is width and 1467 is height. I am new in Swift and not able to make a logic for that.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `|` as a separator and get the two last components from it.

```
let urlArray = url.components(separatedBy: "|")

guard urlArray.count > 2,
    let width = CGFloat(urlArray[urlArray.count - 2]),
    let height = CGFloat(urlArray[urlArray.count - 1]) else {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the string is only part of a full URL, you can't use the `URL` or `URLComponents` types that would make this easy.

You could separate the string based on the "?" and "|" characters something like this. However, this assumes there is only one of each of those characters in the string. You may need to add additional error checking.

Given your above string, this will return a `[Int]` that contains the two values.

```
let url = "uploads/story/5503113.jpg?854|1467"

let dimensions = url.components(separatedBy: "?")
    .dropFirst()
    .flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "|") }
    .flatMap { Int($0) }
```

You could also create a regular expression to do it. But it may be more complicated

Answer (score 0):

A (safe) solution using `range(of` and `substring(from/to`

```
let url = "uploads/story/5503113.jpg?854|1467"
if let queryRange = url.range(of: "?") {
    let query = url.substring(from: queryRange.upperBound)
    if let pipeRange = query.range(of: "|") {
        let width = query.substring(to: pipeRange.lowerBound)
        let height = query.substring(from: pipeRange.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
let picWithDimensions = "uploads/story/5503113.jpg?854|1467"
let nsString = picWithDimensions as NSString
let regexForPics = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*\\?(\\d+)\\|(\\d+)")
let result = regexForPics.matches(in: picWithDimensions,range: NSMakeRange(0,nsString.length))[0]
let width = nsString.substring(with: result.rangeAt(1))
let height = nsString.substring(with: result.rangeAt(2))
print(width," ",height)
```